# How to prevent avplayer of cell - Tableview from reinitialize

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am stuck into a big problem.
I have one tableview which has videoplayer - AVPlayer
I have 10 cells and each playing video. but the problem is that when i 
scroll tableview the player get reinitialized and video play from 
start.I want to prevent this re-initialzation and play video like twitter 
which play as we leave as lastWhat code should tried ? I have tried multiple code but get not succeed

```
    Code is here

    if (Arr_avPlayer.count > indexPath.row){
        Cell_TVC * cell = (Cell_TVC *)[Arr_avPlayer 
      objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }

     //    Cell_TVC *cell = (Cell_TVC *)[tableView 
        dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell_TVC" 
        forIndexPath:indexPath];

         **Cell_TVC *cell = [[Cell_TVC alloc] init];**

           //    Cell_TVC *cell =  [tableView 

                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell_TVC"];
          //    if (!cell) {
          //        cell = [[Cell_TVC 

                 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                         reuseIdentifier:@"Cell_TVC"];
         //              
         //    }



      AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL 
      fileURLWithPath:[self filepath:[myIntegers 
      objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] options:nil];

      cell.avPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
      cell.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] 
      initWithPlayerItem:cell.avPlayerItem];

    cell.avPlayerLayer =  [[AVPlayerLayer alloc] init];
    cell.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer 
    playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.avPlayer];
    cell.lblTime.text = @"0.0";

    CGRect contentViewFrame = cell.contentView.frame;
    contentViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
    contentViewFrame.origin.y = 25;
    contentViewFrame.size.width = APP_width;
    contentViewFrame.size.height = APP_width * 0.55;
    cell.contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel 
     alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((cell.contentView.frame.size.width / 2 
    ) - 100, contentViewFrame.size.height + 10, 200, 100)];

    //lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02f:%02f", dMinutes11, 
                 dSeconds11];

    lbl.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.avPlayerLayer setFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
    [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:cell.avPlayerLayer];

    [Arr_avPlayer insertObject:cell atIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];


    if i write the cell like below

    Cell_TVC *cell = [[Cell_TVC alloc] init];

     i am not able to acess the property of cell and when i use like 
    below

     if (!cell)
     {
               cell = [[Cell_TVC 
                 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell_TVC"];

     }
```

the player index change and video get change its index
**How to get ride of this problem ?**

Comment: u need to maintain the seek time of AVPlayer  on datasource of tableview

Comment: From where is that code? `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? You need Your code is messy, please format your question. Also, please, use dequeuing, and use the reuse of cells. Avoid adding subview there also, because of reusing.

Comment: Anbu.Karthik right now i dont want seektime i just want a way to prevent reinitialzing of avplayer

Comment: Larme : this code is written in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UItableview, Its obvious behavior. UItableview  dont keep all the cell's in memory. As cell disappear from screen, tableview remove that and add it again when you scroll down/up  (when new cell appear on screen). 
You can't change this behavior of UItableview.

There is ugly solution available: Which is to resize your tableview to `height = HeightOfCell * numberOfCell.`  But this is not suggested. because this may create memory problem.

Better solution is to keep track of Seek times. You can use [didEndDisplayingCell](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview?language=objc) to store value of current seek time of Player in cell which will remove. and when cell for that index path appear again (cellforrow) you can seek player to stored value.